# Speed up opening a file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've found that a script I have spends about a significant chunk of its run time opening (binary) files, through the built-in `open(filename, "rb")` function. According to my profiler, 7890 calls to `open` cost 129.2 seconds, for an average of about 16.4 milliseconds per call. This seems kind of high to me. (Especially considering the mere 25 seconds in total reading the contents of said files, even though a typical file will be ~MB (order of magnitude) in size.)

I'm wondering if there's a way for me to speed it up, but I don't know much about what the `open` function does behind the scenes. Specifically:

- These files are located on a my storage disk, good old-fashioned 7200 RPM disk. Would it speed things up if I dump them on my SSD? (I imagine this would cause reading the files to be slower than opening them though.)
- The files in question are in relatively deep (9 layers) folder structure. Does this impact the speed of opening the files? (I.e. does the OS have to spend significantly more time converting the file path (a string) to a location on the disk?)

Comment: Both tests you can do yourself within 5 minutes.

Comment: 1. Yes (No) 2. No (No)

Comment: why opening files all the time? alternative is store everything in a zip and use zip to lookup the files. file access is costly, you experience that specially when you have a lot of small files

Comment: You may want to consider using ramdisk

Answer (score 0):

The python side of the open function should not be a performance issue. It is usually the underlying os open call. Check if you have some antivirus that might do stuff for each open call. The 16 ms per open call is unusually high. On my machine a open to a cold file is under 100usec.

If you are on linux and investigating this is worth it, then try strace and perf.
http://www.brendangregg.com/linuxperf.html